# How to change string in .plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, plist

I need that a string in a .plist file could be changed within the app with a "save" button. My plist is a simple array of strings, I need that when the user taps "Save" the string could be modified. Sorry for my bad english. Thank you

Comment: Your English is fine. The problem is that your question shows no effort. What have you tried so far? What is the exact issue you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first extract your plist data and then you have to set the values and then again you have to write like that below:-

```
NSString *docPath =@"your Path";
NNSMutableDictionary* updateVal=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:docPath];
[updateVal setObject:@"yourString" forKey:@"key"];
[updateVal writeToFile:docPath atomically:YES];
```

Note:- As rmaddy mentioned in the comment that docPath should not be in the app's resource bundle.

Comment: Just make sure `docPath` isn't in the app's resource bundle.